# How to get whats NOT in a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

If I have two generic lists.  How do I find what's NOT in the other list using LINQ?

Here is my obj class:

```
 public class tobj
 {      
    public string column1;
    public string column2;
 }
```

Here are the arrays

```
 tobj[] array1 = 
 { 
        new tobj { "1", "1" }, new tobj { "2", "2" }, new tobj { "3", "3" } 
 };

 tobj[] array2 = 
 { 
     new tobj { "2", "2" }, new tobj { "3", "3" }, new tobj { "4", "4" } 
 };

 var diff = array1.FinfDiff(array2); 

 foreach (var value in diff)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(value.column1); // 1
 }
```

This code not tested yet.

Comment: By "not in" the other list, i assume you mean both column1 and column2 as a pair?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. They must be as a pair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Except`.  Given that you have a custom type, though, you'll want to override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` so that it works well with Linq.

This is because Linq strives for efficiency, so it can use `HashSet<T>` and other mechanisms to quickly determine if items are possibly equivalent or not (items that are equivalent *must* have same hash code, or your hash code is bad).  So it's not just enough to implement `Equals()`, you must also implement `GetHashCode()` when using methods of this type with custom classes.

For example:

```
    public class tobj : IEquatable<tobj>
    {
        public string column1;
        public string column2;

        public bool Equals(tobj other)
        {
            return other != null ? Equals(column1, other.column1) && Equals(column2, other.column2) : false;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as tobj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // seed the code
            int hash = 13;

            // use some primes to mix in the field hash codes...
            hash = hash * 17 + column1.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 17 + column2.GetHashCode();

            return hash
        }
    }
```

Now that you have GetHashCode() and Equals() overridden (I like implementing `IEquatable<T>` myself as well), you can use `Except()`:

```
        var results = array1.Except(array2);

        foreach (var i in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.column1 + ":" + i.column2);
        }
```

I'd recommend seeing [this SO thread on algorithms for hash codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) as well for tips on implementing a good one.

Also, as a side note, some types (such as `KeyValuePair`, `Tuple`, and anonymous types) already implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` correctly for equivalence in such a way that they take into account their individual components.

Comment: Perfect man. And as you said I had to go study up on hash codes. C# is awesome

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Except method available to IEnumerable.  It's easy to implement.  You can see an example outlined here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
array2.ForEach(x => array1.Remove(x));
```

what stays in array1 is your result

**edit:**
I dont look at first sight, that items are not "simple" objects... as James write, you need to override equal